# Function didn`t render_template Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

I'm trying to open a page, and the function does not return.
When I click on the button, the function works, but the `render_template` does not happen and I remain on the previous page

```
<script>
var from = '{{ d_from.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") }}';
    var till = '{{ d_till.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") }}';

    $(function () {
        $("#reservation").daterangepicker({
            "locale": {
                "format": "DD/MM/YYYY"
            },
            "opens": "right",
            "showDropdowns": true,
            "showWeekNumbers": true
        }, function (start, end, label) {
            from= start.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
            till = end.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
        });
    });
    $( "#go" ).click(function() {
         var formData = $('#form').serialize(),
           times = { d_from: from, d_till: till },
           data = formData  + '&' + $.param(times);

         $.get('{{ url_for("reporting_backoffice.updates_report") }}', data );
    });
<\script>

{% block report_block_content %}
    <form id="form">

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="reservation"
                       value="{{ d_from.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") }} - {{ d_till.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") }}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                {{ wtf.form_field(form.projects, class="form-control select2") }}
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="go">{{ _("Download report") }}</button>

{% endblock %}
```

**app.py**

```
@app.route("/updates/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def updates_report():
    return render_template("modules/reporting/updates_report.html")
```

When I press a button in the terminal, I get:
`"GET /administration/reports/updates/?projects=1&d_from=07%2F14%2F2017&d_till=07%2F14%2F2017 HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

But if I go through the reference function it works and returns `<a href="{{ url_for("reporting_backoffice.updates_report") }}">"Go"</a>`

Comment: What render_template? You don't call that function in your code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I corrected the question

Comment: Why are you using Ajax here? Nothing happens because the JS does not prevent the default action, or do anything with the result of the Ajax call, but if you want to go to a new page anyway why are you bothering with Ajax?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because I'm using a `datepicker` and I need to pass in the function date. The date is placed in a variable `time`

Comment: Probably just add the anchor tag inside a button tag ?

Comment: Rather you should get the date picker callback function to place the value in a hidden field in the form, and submit it normally.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I do not understand one thing, why the function is called, but does not return render_template?

Comment: But why do you think that is the case? It *does* call it, but your Ajax throws away the response.